# How to set time interval to get frames from input video?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-streaming, opencv3.1

I m trying to get frames from input video for particular time interval.so suggest me any solution that would be helpful for me.Tell me how to set time limit in the following code.

```
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('baahubali2.mp4')
vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,1000)

success, image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True

while success:
    success, image = vidcap.read()
    print('Read a new frame: ', success)
    cv2.imwrite("/home/kapil/Documents/major/image/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     
    count += 1
```

Comment: You need to devise a formula using FPS of video and number of frames you have fetched to calculate the time elapsed in video and `break` accordingly.

Comment: can you show in the code?

Comment: You can measure fps and get specific number of frames

Comment: No suppose the video length of 3.42 minutes and i want frames from 1.2 to 1.9 min.for this task what i have to do?

Comment: This is the first time I see this kind of syntax in C++.

Comment: this code in python.

Comment: So why that flag C++ and no flag Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
import cv2


start_time_ms = 1000
stop_time_ms = 2000
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('baahubali2.mp4')


count = 0
success = True

while success and vidcap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) < start_time_ms:
    success, image = vidcap.read()

while success and vidcap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) <= stop_time_ms:
    success, image = vidcap.read()
    print('Read a new frame: ', success)
    cv2.imwrite("/home/kapil/Documents/major/image/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)    
    count += 1
```

Start and stop time are specified in milliseconds. Frames are read doing nothing until `start_time_ms` and frames are then written as images until `stop_time_ms` or end of video.

Comment: while success and vidcap.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) < start_time_ms:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC'

Comment: I have no error running this whole script, I get the right images at the end (with one of my videos). Perhaps the installation of opencv is different for you than for me, then replace `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` by `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` like in your example if it runs for you.

Comment: I installed opencv (just to help you) on ubuntu using `apt-get python-opencv`, perhaps my version is older or newer than yours and there are slight differences, but you just have to find where is stored `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` attribute.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer as solution to your problem if it did indeed solve it!

Comment: yes thanks..i used cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC..its working

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois, Can you tell me how should I do this when I have multiple time stamps? Like I want frames between 1-5 seconds and then from 10-16 seconds?

Comment: Just use the same technique: perform a while loop with only a call to `read()` to make time advance to 1 second, then another loop with call to `read()` then `imwrite()` to make time advance to 5 seconds while getting images, then continue with only call to `read()` to make time advance to 10 seconds, and again one with `read()` and `imwrite()` until 16 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the solution that I used to get the output, I think it will help**

```
import cv2

import os

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidoname)

time_skips = float(2000) #skip every 2 seconds. You 
need to modify this

count = 0
success,image = cap.read()
while success:
    cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 
    (count*time_skips))    
    # move the time
    success,image = cap.read()
    count += 1

# release after reading    
cap.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
start_time_ms = 120000
stop_time_ms = 150000
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/Players Hunting on Neymar Lionel Messi 
                            Cristiano Ronaldo ● Horror Fouls &amp Tackles HD.mp4')

count = 0
success = True
vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,start_time_ms)
while success and vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) <= stop_time_ms:
  success, image = vidcap.read()
  print('Read a new frame: ', success)
  cv2.imwrite("/content/image/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)    
  count += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to stack-Overflow community and thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)